# decide if the set function $\nu$ defined is a measure

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,F,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $A \in F$ with $\mu(A)>0$. In each case below, decide if the set function $\nu$ defined there is a measure. Prove that it is a measure or provide a counter-example in each case.

(i) $\nu(B)=\mu(A \cap B), B \in F$

(ii) $\nu(B)=\mu(A \cup B), B \in F$

Comment: 1, try to prove that it is indeed a measure 2. empty set